# how to find the word with max count in several text files in java?

Tags: java

now i have two arrays. one is string array with words in it. and a count array with corresponding counts in it. below i have printed them together....

ex:

```
gladiator 8  
yamaha 6
gladiator 4
bike 6
brake 4
long 4
time 6
gladiator 35
yamaha 39
bike 17
gladiator 16
ss 19
type 16
yamaha 21
gladiator 15
india 8
yamaha 17
bike 7
gladiator 15
shine 9
yamaha 9
bike 8
gladiator 14
india 8
yamaha 18
bike 7
gladiator 9
```

so now i have first "gladiator" "8" then "gladiator" "4"... so on....
finally i want it as "gladiator" "12"..... like wise

Comment: You have tagged your question `scanner`, so it seems you know that this class might be appropriate. Maybe you should read the documentation, and see if that helps? If this does not help, try a simple Java-tutorial first.

Comment: I don't know if scanner is actually the right choice when you can just split on space.

Comment: see i am able to get the word's and the count separately in two arrays. but now i have to find the word with max count

Comment: Please check my edited answer below.Is it your expected output?

Comment: no thats not it... if i have the duplicate entries then i have add that also...

Answer (score 1):

- iterate through list of file names
- open file
- read in line
- split line on space with `String.split(" ")`
- convert second element to int with `Integer.parseInt(array[1])`
- keep track of highest count, storing `array[0]` when count is higher.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse through the files and store the names and the length in a map.

```
Map <String,Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>() ;
```

Then iterate through the map and find the max count.
 The key corresponding to the max count will be the word.

```
public class CountWord {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Map <String,Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>() ;
    int maxCount = 0;
    int currentCount = 0;
    wordMap.put("Yamaha", new Integer(6));
    wordMap.put("Bat", new Integer(3));
    wordMap.put("Honda", new Integer(5));
    wordMap.put("Book", new Integer(4));
    wordMap.put("CutiePie", new Integer(8));
    wordMap.put("Project", new Integer(7));

    Collection countList = wordMap.values();
    Iterator itr = countList.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext()){       
        currentCount = ((Integer)itr.next()).intValue();
        if(maxCount < currentCount){
            maxCount = currentCount;
        }           
    }

    for (Object key: wordMap.keySet()) {            
        if(((Integer)wordMap.get(key)).intValue() == maxCount){
            System.out.println("The word is : "+key.toString());
        }
    }
}

   }
```

Comment: i want the count to be added of those duplicate entries

Comment: Duplicate entries can't occur in the map ie the words can't repeat itself since they are the keys.If you have two words with same count it will print both of them.